# How undo a git rebase --abort?

Tags: git, github

I was performing a git rebase before working on my changes. Unfortunately I didnt finish the rebase and without realising rebase was in progress I started working on my changes. Later when I was building I realised rebase was in progress causing a bunch of conflicts so i did git rebase --abort and lost my working changes as well.
Anything I can do to get that back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Anything I can do to get that back?

No. The unit of preservation in Git is the *commit*. Anything not committed is transient.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, be sure you commit/stash/somehow preserve current work progress to not lose anything again.

You shoud be able to get to the last successfull rebased commits from the reflog:

```
git reflog
```

Apply some research and get the hash of the last commit of a rebase operation you are/were satisfied with and rebase to that point with interactive mode:

```
git rebase -i that-hash
```

Then choose wisely the commits left to rebase and you should be ok.

Comment: "First of all, be sure you commit/stash/somehow preserve current work progress to not lose" But that is exactly what was _not_ done. Therefore this answer is not useful.

Comment: Also please note that a stash is a commit so there is no need to say commit/stash. A commit is a commit.

Comment: I see, I thought Denise is missing the rebase operation. But it is the additional work what is missing. Sorry, got it wrong.